# ng-drag-drop delete drag data from source list

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

for my Angular App I am using the [ng-drag-drop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-drag-drop#demo) package. I have three lists with draggable items. The user should be able to drag any item to any list. The item will then be removed from the initial list and inserted into the new list. The example provided by ng-drag-drop, however, only shows the usage with two lists. With to lists it is easy to determine where the item comes from as there is only one option.
E.g. I have to lists A & B. If I drag an item from list A I know that I have to delete it in list A and add it to list B. 
However, if I have three lists A, B & C. And I move an item from A to C. The origin of this item can either be A or B. Hence, I don't know where to delete it from.
Here is my current code:
This is my HTML structure:

```
<div class="columnBox" droppable [dragOverClass]="'drag-target-border'"
     [dragHintClass]="'drag-hint'" (onDrop)="onListADrop($event)">
  <div class="task" *ngFor="let item of listA" draggable [dragClass]="'drag-over'" [dragData]="item">
    {{ item.name }}
  </div>
</div>

<div class="columnBox" droppable [dragOverClass]="'drag-target-border'"
     [dragHintClass]="'drag-hint'" (onDrop)="onListBDrop($event)">
  <div class="task" *ngFor="let item of listB" draggable [dragClass]="'drag-over'" [dragData]="item">
    {{ item.name }}
  </div>
</div>

<div class="columnBox" droppable [dragOverClass]="'drag-target-border'"
     [dragHintClass]="'drag-hint'" (onDrop)="onListCDrop($event)">
  <div class="task" *ngFor="let item of listC" draggable [dragClass]="'drag-over'" [dragData]="item">
    {{ item.name }}
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I created three lists A, B, C.

Now this is my Typescript code:

```
listA = [
    {name: 'milk'},
    {name: 'juice'}
  ];

  listB = [
    {name: 'beer'},
    {name: 'water'}
  ];

  listC = [
    {name: 'wine'}
  ];

  onListADrop(e: DropEvent) {
    this.listA.push(e.dragData);
    this.removeItem(e.dragData, this.listB);
  }

  onListBDrop(e: DropEvent) {
    this.listB.push(e.dragData);
    this.removeItem(e.dragData, this.listA);
  }

  onListCDrop(e: DropEvent) {
    this.listC.push(e.dragData);
    this.removeItem(e.dragData, this.listA);
  }

  removeItem(item: any, list: Array<any>) {
    let index = list.map(function (e) {
      return e.title
    }).indexOf(item.title);
    list.splice(index, 1);
  }
```

So for List A and B adding and deleting works fine. However, if I would drag an Item from list C to list A, it would look in the B list to delete the item. How can I tell each "removeItem" method to delete from the list of the data's origin?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have a function for each drop event, as you can check in cdk docs, you could do in your html something like this:

```
<div cdkDropListGroup>
  <!-- All lists in here will be connected. -->
  <div cdkDropList id='delete'(cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" ></div>
  <div cdkDropList id='listX' (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"<!--here you put your info and settings-->><div cdkDrag object,classes,*ngFor, etc ( >{{ name }}</div><!--repeat this for each list-->
</div>
```

and in your ts file, what you need is one function to handle the drop event:

```
 drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
     moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
     transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                    event.container.data,
                    event.previousIndex,
                    event.currentIndex);
    }
 }
```

and of course you can add an extra "if" before all of it, asking if the drop container is the 'delete' container, so it would be something like this:

```
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if(event.id === 'delete') {transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                    event.container.data,
                    event.previousIndex,
                    event.currentIndex); deleteitem(event){this.deleteArray = []} else {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
     moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
     transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                    event.container.data,
                    event.previousIndex,
                    event.currentIndex);
    }
 }}
```